# How to use Apache Poi in Sketchware?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sketchware

i want edit excel files programmatically by sketchware.
I couldn't implement Apache-poi, tried adding the libraries to the 'local_libs' folder, but that didn't help. Can someone please help me to implement Apache-poi in Sketchware.

Comment: POI is very memory heavy. Just my opinion, but if I planned to support spreadsheet usage on android, I would use Google Sheets and there are videos about using doing that using Sketchware - eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ox_cdqtue0I

Comment: i wish to edit xlsx files offline... how can i do that